# Stopwords filtering not working entirely?

Tags: c#, string, nlp

Good afternoon,

I am running a function in C# designed to remove certain "stopwords" from a string such as "the, or, it" so it will be more useful in natural language processing. However the function will for some reason not remove the first instance of the word.

For example

input:
The lion the witch and the wardrobe

return:
the lion witch and wardrobe    (I am not using 'and' as a stopword as it can be useful)

My function is below:

```
    private void filterStopWords(string textToFilter)
    {
        textToFilter.ToLower();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(textToFilter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            if (textToFilter.Contains(stopWords[i]))
            {
                builder.Replace(stopWords[i], " ");
            }
        }
        filterQueryBox.Text = builder.ToString();
    }
```

Stopwords[] is an array containing all my stopwords.

Thanks in advance for any response that may help me here!

Comment: `ToLower` method returns new string instance. You need to assign these results current or new string reference.

Comment: I understand that, however it does not explain why it removed the second and third "the" but not the first?

Comment: I thought that at first but I made sure it was lowercase T

Comment: My guess would be that your stopword is " the " with leading and trailing blanks. The first occurence of "the" doesn't have a blank in front of it, so it doesn't match.

Comment: That is absolutely right. Thanks a lot!
Bah, stupid mistake :)
If you post this an an answer I will happily accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your stopword is " the " with leading and trailing blanks. The first occurence of "the" doesn't have a blank in front of it, so it doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

You almost there..

- [`String.ToLower`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns new `string` instance. You need to assign it to another or same string reference.
- [`StringBuilder.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns new `StringBuilder` instance. You need to assign it to another or same `StringBuilder` reference.

And since you first use `ToLower` than replace the `"the"`, you shouldn't have `"the.."` part in your instance. Because it matches in your `stopWords` array item.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     filterStopWords("The lion the witch and the wardrobe");
}

private static void filterStopWords(string textToFilter)
{
     var stopWords = new [] {"The", "or", "it"};
     textToFilter = textToFilter.ToLower();
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(textToFilter);
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
            if (textToFilter.Contains(stopWords[i]))
            {
                builder = builder.Replace(stopWords[i], " ");
            }
     }
     var result = builder.ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Result will be;

```
  lion   w ch and   wardrobe
```